# How does Django know the host name for a FileField?

Tags: python, django

How does Django know the host name for a FileField that points to my MEDIA_ROOT location? I need to replace the current host name by another one. How do I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think by default django uses `HOST = ''` that equals 127.0.0.1. You can change it in settings.py however I do not know how to use two different hosts.

Comment: The image field url is relative. What do you try to do?